# Determining rating function for severity measure

Tags: regression, rating, frequency-severity

I have data of a medical experiment and want to run a linear regression. More precisely, I have severity degrees of a disease of two independent groups (treatment and control group). The severity degrees are categorical with values {0,1,2,3} (0 meaning no disease, whereas 3 represents a widespread of the disease). In each session, a number of samples is taken from a subject. Next, the samples are rated according to their severity degree. These ratings are averaged over all samples taken and recoded into percentages. Hence, results of two subjects could look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
| Group     | 0     | 1   | 2   | 3     |
-----------------------------------------
| Control   | 0.195 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.005 |
| Treatment | 0.499 | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.001 |
-----------------------------------------
```

For the regression analysis, I want to code the severities into a single score. A first thought would be to sum up severities 1 to 3. That is, the score of the first row of the table would be `score(0.5,0.3,0.005) = 0.5+0.3+0.005 = 0.805`. But this is not a good score function since it disregards the ordinal nature of the severities (e.g. `score(0.005,0.3,0.5)` would yield the same value even though its greatly more severe).

The next idea is to weight the different levels, i.e. `score(s_1,s_2,s_3) = w_1*s_1 + w_2*s_2 + w_3*s_3` (in case of a linear function). Obviously, the weights should satisfy `w1 <= w_2 <= w3`. Is there any good (maybe even common) way to determine such weights?